# How can I disable scroll lock when switching layouts?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

I updated my Xubuntu 12.04 xfce 4.8 to xfce 4.10 and now when I switch keyboard layouts it activates scroll lock.

How can I disable scroll lock when I switch layout?

Answer (score 7):

This helps sometimes, but if not:

Read the configuration in

```
dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options
```

Then remove the `'grp_led:scroll'` part and write it back like so:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'numpad:microsoft']"
```

Please note that tools like gnome tweek may restore the options.

Also' make sure your .profile or .bashrc do not contain settings that may restore the option..

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/keyboard
```

change

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

save, exit, and reboot.

Comment: Problem started after switching to 18.04.
The solution above worked after restrt' but after a terminal is opened the behaviour regresses and the LED is blinking again.

Seems like unpredictable behavior of this "feature"

Comment: but this is not working after restart