# Why do Japanese keyboard arrow keys scroll in LibreOffice Calc but move cell with US keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout, libreoffice, 21.04, wayland

After upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04, the arrow keys on my USB Japanese 108-key keyboard scroll in LibreOffice Calc as though scroll lock is toggled on (even though the scroll lock light is not on) instead of moving the selected cell. (Actually, this happens with the US-intl keyboard layout too.) The arrow keys work as expected in other programs though, including LibreOffice Writer.

If I switch to the default US keyboard layout, the arrow keys work properly: moving the selected cell.

I've tried removing `grp_led:scroll` from `XKBOPTIONS="grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"` in `/etc/default/keyboard`, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390324/how-can-i-disable-scroll-lock-when-switching-layouts), but it did not fix it.

I also tried uninstalling LibreOffice and removing the config files as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1272396/cannot-disable-scroll-lock-in-libreoffice-calc-using-a-dell-xps), but that didn't fix it either.

This wasn't a problem in Ubuntu 20.10, so something has changed related to the upgrade.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wayland seems to be the problem.

To fix it, before logging in, I clicked the gear icon in the lower right corner of the login screen and selected Xorg.

This and [other issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344175/nautilus-crashes-when-trying-to-open-another-window-by-right-clicking-the-nautil) are fixed!

Comment: Good that you found a workaround. Can you please submit a bug report? Not sure which package is correct, but I'd pick `gnome-shell`.

Comment: With my previous experience the problem was with `grp_led:scroll` . See https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=111627#c8 .

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Bug report is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1939186

Comment: Bug report has been moved to mutter here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1939186